# Android facebook login error?

Tags: android, android-facebook

I'm using facebook login in my application. i'm using Facebook SDK 3.0.

if facebook app is available facebook login working fine , if facebook app not available showing this error.

[image]

if any body know the reason tell me

Comment: Check whether your app id is correct

Comment: i have two android device for testing. one device working fine because i install facebook app. another one not working because i don't have facebook app. i don't know yesterday working fine today getting problem.